# Rspec: How can I have many controllers in one test? How can I change controllers in a test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm running into an interesting issue when I try to write a full walk through test.

First, I'd like to acknowledge that tests should be discrete and specific things. This fact I know.. but :)

But as with a play and learning lines, I think it's a good idea to have a full walk through test before you open the doors. To this end I want to write a massive integration test, that hits a pile of controllers.  It will be super slow so I've already isolated it to run only when asked for. But now I'm stuck

I can't seem to figure out how to "hit" the controllers.

I've tried setting my test type to 'integration' and stipulating. I followed the steps outlined in this questions answer [post to a different controller in an rspec test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290035/post-to-a-different-controller-in-an-rspec-test)
And I threw in a 1/0 in the controller, and it never hit.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. I figured this out, thanks to other answers.. I'm just writing it out simpler, for my own notes.. and for future hunters.

```
describe 'Payments Integration', :type => :request do
  let(:attributes) { p 'blabla' }
  it 'should create user and billing details'  do
      expect{
        post '/api/account', account: attributes
      }.to change(User,:count).by(1)
      user = User.find(json['account']['id'])
      auth  = user.authentication_token

      expect{ 
        post '/api/billing_details', auth_token: auth, credit_card: valid_card
      }.to change(BillingDetail,:count).by(1)
  end
end
```

I had many posts and puts, but this code is enough to get anyone started.

Comment: If you put this test in `spec/requests` you won't need to specify the `type` manually on the test.

Comment: Yeah..the problem is that I have it in a lib folder   spec/lib/payments And the filename is _full_integration_spec.rb   I don't think requests is specific enough..

Comment: I also have the test tagged so it only runs when I specifically ask for it, but that's another question :)